# how to do php unit testing post data passing from javascript to controller?

Tags: php, phpunit, phalcon

I am using phalcon framework and i want to write a unit test.

In JS I am using Post Method and In my controller

```
public function controllerAction {
    $this->view->disable();
    $body = $this->request->getRawBody();

    $data = json_decode($body, true);
    $status = array('success'=>true);

    if (!$data) {
        throw new \Exception("Invalid JSON Body");
    }}
```

I need a test function to pass post data to the controller 
Thanks

Comment: This wouldn't be a unit test, but basically what I'd say is your controller action, and request data classes should be unit-tested on their own which means a test here on such basic functionality would be moot. If you're using a pre-built MVC framework then they likely already have the unit tests for these functions built and tested.

Comment: Can you share the testcase class? What try you done?

Comment: You should look into injecting (mocking) your own request via the DI [list of services used by default](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/di.html#service-name-conventions)

Answer (score 0):

Load **REST** module, example for Codeception unit tests:

```
modules:
    enabled:
        - Asserts
        - Db
        - \Helper\Unit
        - \Helper\Database
        - Phalcon:
            bootstrap: ../app/config/bootstrap.php
            cleanup: true
            savepoints: true
        - REST:
            depends: Phalcon
```

Then in your test method send post to controller with mocked data and check response:

```
public function  someTest(\UnitTester $I) {
    $I->sendPOST('/url_to_method', file_get_contents(codecept_data_dir() . 'testData.json'));

    $I->seeResponseContainsJson([
        "success" => "true"
    ]);

}
```

And your controller method should be slightly different, you need to call **getJsonRawBody** instead of getRawBody, and to return actual **$success** on success so:

```
public function controllerAction {
    $this->view->disable();
    $body = $this->request->getJsonRawBody();

    $data = json_decode($body, true);
    $status = array('success'=>true);

    if (!$data) {
        throw new \Exception("Invalid JSON Body");
    }
    else{
        $this->response->setContent(json_encode($status));
        return $this->response;
    }
}
```